# Contents of document.ready() function do not run after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a Drupal commerce site which has a few drop down menus, these call different products from the database in real time using Ajax.

My problem is that once any of these changes are made, the functions inside my document.ready() don't work.

I have tried

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    OnloadFunction();

    $(".ajax-processed").change(function() {
    OnloadFunction();
    });
});

function OnloadFunction ()
{
jQuery('.form-submit').click(
    function () {
        jQuery('#loader').css({display:'block'});
    }); 
}
```

How can I call the function OnloadFunction when a change in the drop down menu is made?

Comment: By definition, the DOM ready handler only fires _once_... as soon as the DOM is ready.  However, any handler functions inside are initialized and will continue to work at any time.  If you need something to happen when something else changes, you'll need to capture that event similar to how you already captured the `click` and `change` events for these other things.

Comment: Well once any change is made in the drop down menus and the page updates via Ajax, the jquery that makes the div #'loader appear fails to work anymore

Comment: You're going to need to improve this question.  We cannot see your `ajax` code or your HTML, and would have no idea what your ajax is doing to the page.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's not an issue with a target element being removed I have tested for this and I am using a class which remains the same after an ajax change

Comment: Please carefully read my previous comment and click the two links I provided.  Posting such poorly written questions helps nobody.

Answer (score -1):

In order to invoke a function upon drop down change set       $('#yourDropdownId').change(yourFunction)

Answer (score -2):

I solved this issue by using

`jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function($)`